# IIS initial load is too slow when deploy a DLL

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

During debugging phase, I refresh (copy and overwrite) a DLL in order to test changes on my local machine, so IIS recycles, and that takes zillion years to complete, any idea how to enhance this performance?

Comment: A single dll change should not trigger IIS recycle. Have you checked event viewer?

Comment: Can you give some more information? What do you mean by deploy a new DLL? Is this a reference library or do you mean your compiled site. Are you using an IDE to test or are you just testing the site from a browser? Is the site hosted locally or on a server?

Comment: You need to explain the following phrase because it really is not a standard or documented  procedure:   "I deploy a new DLL from time to time in order to test changes on my local machine, and IIS recycles". Give an example.

Comment: It can be for many reasons. 1. Code performance issue
2. Your computer configuration and so on. Try to refresh your site in iis. Restart iis then try.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I rephrase the question.

Comment: Maybe this article can help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/fastcgi/

Answer (score 2):

Refresh page on site and restart iis. 
Or try the FastCGI.
In order to process requests by using FastCGI, you must first map the path and the specific file name extensions to the FastCGI module and specify the target FastCGI process as the script processor.